# Не выходит рекурсия

Tags: c, рекурсия, c++

Добрый вечер господа!

Есть код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include "graphics.h"
    #include "circle.h"
    using namespace std;
    void Draw(int x, int y, int r, int l);
    void main()
    {   
        int x=400,y=30,r=10,l=1;
        SgHideConsole(); //Скрываем консоль.
        SgCreate(800,650,"Урок №5");
        while(SgIsActive())
        {
            SgBeginDraw(); //Начинаем рисовать.
            Draw(x,y,r,l);
            SgEndDraw(); //Заканчиваем рисовать.
            SgPause(10); 
        }
        SgDestroy(); //Высвобождаем память.
        SgShowConsole(); //Возврашаем консоль.
    }
    void Draw(int x, int y, int r, int l)
    {
        SgClearScreen(SgRGB(255,255,255)); //Задаем белый цвет фона.
        SgSelectPen(2,SgRGB(0,0,0));

//Начало фигуры.
        Circle(x,y,r); //Верх.
        Circle(x-20,y+20,10); //Лево.
        Circle(x+20,y+20,10); //Право.
        Circle(x,y+40,10); //Низ.
        Circle(x,y+20,r+10); //Середина.
//Конец фигуры.    
        if(l<4)
        {
            Draw(x-40,y+40,10,l+1);
        }
        else return;
    }
```

Нужно рекурсивно нарисовать фигуру, но столкнулся с проблемой, что вместо 3 фигур, выводит только одну с параметрами последней фигуры, как сделать чтобы выводило все 3 фигуры?

Comment: Точнооо, такая глупая ошибка! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю этой графической библиотеки, но думаю, что вся беда в этом вызове:

```
SgClearScreen(SgRGB(255,255,255)); //Задаем белый цвет фона.
```

Вынесите его за ф-ю Draw